# React Native ScrollView Horizontal

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a system in which there is one horizontal ScrollView. But I don't know why, this scrollView doesn't work.

There is my code:

```
 <ScrollView
    pagingEnabled={true}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    style={{
      margin: 10,
    }}
  >
    {brandName.map((element, index) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            margin: 10,
            left: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              borderRadius: 20,
              borderColor: "#ff7b0d",
              borderWidth: 1,
              width: "55%",
              height: "120%",
              backgroundColor: "#ff7b0d",
              color: "#fff",
              textAlign: "center",
            }}
          >
            {element}
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{right: 18}}>X</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    })}
    <View
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        top: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          paddingLeft: 10,
          borderRadius: 20,
          borderColor: "#ff7b0d",
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#ff7b0d",
          color: "#fff",
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          paddingVertical: 3,
          left: 10,
          width: "60%",
          height: "60%",
        }}
      >
        Trie : {listOfSort}
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{paddingVertical: 3, right: 10}}>X</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

I tried to remove and change some things but nothing change.
Could someone explain to me where the problem is?
Thanks you in advance I continue by my side!

Comment: What's it doing right now? Is there a vertical scroll? Is there no scroll at all? Double check to make sure the width is enough to allow side scrolling

Comment: There is not any scroll. Should I set a width to this ScrollView ?

Comment: The scrollview will expand on it's own. Maybe try putting some stuff with set widths in the scrollview? That way you could determine whether it's the scrollview of the content causing the problem

Comment: I tried to put ~10  elements in the ScrollView and I got a horizontal Scroll but with just 3 elements, the "maximum width" of the scrollView limit me to see the rest of my list. Do you know why ?

Comment: In theory it should scroll infinitely based on the content. I suppose you could try setting the width based on a formula?

Comment: Yeah but I already tried it but it didn't work ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `flex: 1` to the parent view of your elements. The following adjustment fixes your issue.

```js
<ScrollView
    pagingEnabled={true}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    style={{
      margin: 10,
    }}
  >
    {brandName.map((element, index) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row",
            margin: 10,
            left: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              borderRadius: 20,
              borderColor: "#ff7b0d",
              borderWidth: 1,
              width: "55%",
              height: "120%",
              backgroundColor: "#ff7b0d",
              color: "#fff",
              textAlign: "center",
            }}
          >
            {element}
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{right: 18}}>X</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    })}
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        top: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          paddingLeft: 10,
          borderRadius: 20,
          borderColor: "#ff7b0d",
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#ff7b0d",
          color: "#fff",
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          paddingVertical: 3,
          left: 10,
          width: "60%",
          height: "60%",
        }}
      >
        Trie : {listOfSort}
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{paddingVertical: 3, right: 10}}>X</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: It's almost that but I can't see my last element and my "Trie: {listOfSort}" element (wich is at the end of the row). Do you know why ? And thanks you for your previous help !